# NoMethodError: undefined method `get' for #<Class:0xc3ba52c>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, rake

I have a project totally an api one returning json response. I have an affiliation table associated with other information. All information in my tables is being fetched through rake task. Now the issue is, the project was running fine but not now when I run a rake task it gives an error in .get method as such

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `get' for #<Class:0xc3ba52c>
/home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
```

Here I have used it :

```
@affiliation = Affiliation.get('my_key')
```

If I change this to

```
@affiliation = Affiliation.find_by_key('my_key')
```

It works fine. But unfortunately I do not have access rights to change in it. Moreover I do not understand why has that method stopped working just at a sudden.

I read about this over here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.1/classes/ActiveResource/CustomMethods.html#method-c-get

Can I not make it work some other way:
I really need this integration to work properly. I will be really thankful if someone helps.

Comment: `get` method is for `ActiveResource`, you use `ActiveRecord` here.

Comment: We use ActiveResource base class if we want to fetch data from the API, not with the database. So If your models are inherited with ActiveResource::Base class you should be able to call get on it. If you are using ActiveRecord in models then you will not be able to call get or other active resource methods.